# Does setFeatureCompatibilityVersion need to be run on config servers?

Tags: mongodb

I just upgraded our Mongo cluster from 4.2 to 4.4. Afterwards I opened a mongos session to execute `db.adminCommand( { setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: "4.4" } )`. But the session just hangs. I eventually stopped the op with Ctrl-C. I then logged into each of the shards and executed `db.adminCommand( { getParameter: 1, featureCompatibilityVersion: 1 } )`. Interestingly all shards show *featureCompatibilityVersion of 4.4*. Next I logged into the primary server of the config replica set but the featureCompatibilityVersion shows version 4.2 & target server 4.4.

I'm not sure why the setFeatureCompatibilityVersion command hangs on the mongos instance. But to keep the config replica set current, do I need to execute `db.adminCommand( { setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: "4.4" } )` from the primary server of the config replica set?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turns out there were some ops that took a long time to complete. Eventually the `db.adminCommand( { setFeatureCompatibilityVersion: "4.4" } )` command completed and all config servers and shards now show *featureCompatibilityVersion of 4.4*.